# How to fit the image to to border after rotation in WPF

Tags: wpf, rotatetransform

I have one border inside which am having an image. on button click am rotating that image to 90 degrees.
this is my original image
[image]

The below is after rotation
[image]

As you can after rotation my image doesn't fit into the border. I need it to be fill the border completely. What is am missing here?

Comment: Do you want to smaller image, or rotate your border too?

Comment: I want smaller image. I don't want to rotate the border.the border will remains same size and angle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think, you are using `RenderTransform` to rotate the image.

Instead, use `LayoutTransform`.

See the sample:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Border Width="500" Height="300" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
        <Image Source="sombrero.jpg" Stretch="Fill" x:Name="img" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        </Image>
    </Border>
    
    <Button Content="Rotate" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"></Button>
</StackPanel>
```

Codebehind:

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        img.LayoutTransform = new RotateTransform(90);
    }
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Hope this helps.